# how to resolve jquery custom Timer issue?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datetime, timer

I have created a custom Jquery Timer. but i am facing little problem i dont know that is not working for me. below is my code.

```
  function show(Hos, mins, secds) {

        var hours = Hos;
        var minutes = mins;
        var seconds = secds;
        var dn = "AM";
        if (hours > 12) {
            dn = "PM"
            hours = hours - 12
        }
                    if (hours == 0)
                        hours = 12

        document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + dn
        if (parseInt(seconds) == 59) {
            seconds = 0;
            if (parseInt(minutes) == 59) {
                if (parseInt(hours) == 12) {
                    hours = 0;
                } else {
                    hours = parseInt(hours) + 1;
                }
            } else {

                minutes = parseInt(minutes) + 1;
            }
        } else {
            seconds = parseInt(seconds) + 1;

        }


        setTimeout("show('" + hours + "','" + minutes + "','" + seconds + "'" + " )", 1000)
    }
```

This code is working fine i am passing the hours,mins,seconds first time from the code behind using c#.Now my problem is i want to add "**0**" if the seconds is less than 9 and minutes less than 9 and hours less than 9. i have tried the following trick but i dont know why its not working for me..

```
if (seconds <= 9) {
                seconds = '0' + parseInt(seconds);
            }
```

Please help me..Actually what happens when i tried this . its concatenate 0 with seconds upto 9 but as 9 comes it restarts from 1. That is the problem.

Comment: A couple questions - what is the exact value of seconds when it comes into your if statement - '9' or '09'. And where exactly is the if statement/

Comment: value comes 9 ..and it could be any where before displaying it into label's text

Comment: Why I ask is because if a number starts with 0, parseInt defaults to radix octal, which may lead to some weird issues. try using parseint(seconds, 10) and see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolve this problem using some trick that is as follow:

```
function show(Hos, mins, secds) {

        var hours = Hos;
        var minutes = mins;
        var seconds = parseInt(secds, 10);


        if (hours == 0)
            hours = 12

        if (parseInt(seconds, 10) < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + parseInt(seconds, 10);
        }
        if (parseInt(hours, 10) < 10) {
            hours= "0" + parseInt(hours, 10);
        }
        if (parseInt(minutes, 10) < 10) {
            minutes= "0" + parseInt(minutes, 10);
        }
        document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " "
        if (parseInt(seconds) == 59) {
            seconds = 0;
            if (parseInt(minutes, 10) == 59) {
                if (parseInt(hours, 10) == 24) {
                    hours = 0;
                } else {
                    hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 1;
                }
            } else {

                minutes = parseInt(minutes, 10) + 1;
            }
        } else {
               seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10) + 1;
       }
        setTimeout("show('" + hours + "','" + minutes + "','" + seconds + "'" + " )", 1000)
    }
```

Comment: How about (hours < 10 and seconds < 10)

Comment: Almost there. A couple places missing the 0 on the hours < 10

Answer (score 1):

`seconds = '0' + parseInt(seconds)` will do string addition, since `'0'`, is a string.

When you add a string to a number in javascript, the number will be appended to the string.

Remove the quotes for 0, then it will be treated like number.

P.S. I guess this is the problem you are trying to crack